# @State initial value not resetting variable on init()

Tags: swiftui

I have a segmented control that I am using as a tabs in the toolbar of my app linked to the selectedTab variable.  when I switch tabs the accounts list changes but it does not reset the lines list.  I tried using initialValue on the selected to make sure it reset to 0 but this did not effect it. I tried a print in the init to make sure that the value of selected was 0, after the init.  it was every time but it still did not refresh the lines foreach list.

What am I missing?

```
import SwiftUI
import SQLite3

struct ContentView:View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if shared.selectedTab == 0 {
                LedgerView(ledger: .Accounts)
            } else if shared.selectedTab == 1 {
                LedgerView(ledger: .Budgets)
            } else if shared.selectedTab == 2 {
                ReportsView()
            }
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}

struct LedgerView:View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject

    let ledger:LedgerType
    @State var selected:Int = 0

    init(ledger:LedgerType) {
        self.ledger = ledger
        self._selected = State(initialValue: 0)
    }

    var body:some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                ForEach(shared.accounts.filter({$0.ledger == ledger})) { account in
                    Text(account.name)
                        .background(account.id == self.selected ? Color.accentColor : Color.clear)
                        .onTapGesture {self.selected = account.id}
                }
            }
            Divider()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                ForEach(shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == selected})) { line in
                    Text("Line#\(line.id)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ReportsView:View {
    var body:some View {
        Text("Under Construction ...")
    }
}

class SharedObject:ObservableObject {

    @Published var accounts:[Account] = []
    @Published var journalLines:[JournalLine] = []
    @Published var selectedTab:Int = 0

    init() {
        loadData()    
    }

}

enum LedgerType:Int {
    case Accounts=0,Budgets=1
    var name:String {
        switch(self) {
        case .Accounts: return "Accounts"
        case .Budgets: return "Budgets"
        }
    }
}
struct Account:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var ledger:LedgerType
}
struct Payee:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
}
struct Journal:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var date:Date
    var payeeID:Int
    var memo:String?
}
struct JournalLine:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var journalID:Int
    var accountID:Int
    var amount:Double
}
```

edit abridged demo code to try to isolate the problem

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $shared.selectedTab, label: Text("")) {
                Text("Accounts").tag(0)
                Text("Budgets").tag(1)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Divider()
            if shared.selectedTab == 0 || shared.selectedTab == 1 {
                LedgerView()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}

struct LedgerView:View {

    @State var selected:Int = 0

    init() {
        self._selected = State(initialValue: 0)
        print("LedgerView.init()")
    }

    var body:some View {
        VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
            Text("Selected: \(selected)")
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("")) {
                Text("Account#1").tag(1)
                Text("Account#2").tag(2)
                Text("Account#3").tag(3)
            }
        }
    }

}

class SharedObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab:Int = 0
}
```

Comment: firstly try to pass LedgerView(ledger: .Accounts).environmentObject(shared)

Comment: Would you indicate where is unexpected result happened, because in my test env I did not find any? And provide some model data with witch you see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your recent comment, what you need is @Binding and not @State. To explain: The struct LedgerView is just an *extract* of the picker in a separate view. When you call LedgerView(), this doesn't instantiate a new object. It simply adds the picker view in that place. Therefore, when you need the picker to reset on switching tabs, you need to use binding to reset the picker. Here's the working code. Hope it helps.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject
    @State var selected: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $shared.selectedTab, label: Text("")) {
                Text("Accounts").tag(0)
                Text("Budgets").tag(1)
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Divider()
            if shared.selectedTab == 0 || shared.selectedTab == 1 {
                LedgerView(selected: $selected)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .onReceive(shared.$selectedTab) { newValue in
            self.selected = 0
        }
    }
}

struct LedgerView:View {

    @Binding var selected: Int

    var body:some View {
        VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
            Text("Selected: \(selected)")
            Picker(selection: $selected, label: Text("")) {
                Text("Account#1").tag(1)
                Text("Account#2").tag(2)
                Text("Account#3").tag(3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Earlier answer containing alternate solution]

I've modified your code to make the lines work. I've added sample data to get the code to work. I doubt if the problem is with your data. Also I have modified the enum LedgerType to make it iterable. Here's the working code.

I've modified the following in code:

1. Removed passing ledgerType to LedgerView as the source of truth is

   @EnvironmentObject var shared: SharedObject
2. Added code to select the first account by default when switching tabs. This refreshes the lines when switching between tabs. See the code in .onReceive

Hope this helps. If you need anything, let me know.

```
struct ContentView:View {

    @EnvironmentObject var shared: SharedObject

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $shared.selectedTab, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< LedgerType.allCases.count) { index in
                    Text(LedgerType.allCases[index].rawValue).tag(index)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())

            if shared.selectedTab == 0 || shared.selectedTab == 1 {
                LedgerView()
            } else if shared.selectedTab == 2 {
                ReportsView()
            }
            Spacer()
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }

}

struct LedgerView:View {
    @EnvironmentObject var shared:SharedObject
    @State var selected: Int = 0

    var body:some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                ForEach(shared.accounts.filter({ $0.ledger == LedgerType.allCases[shared.selectedTab] })) { account in
                    Text(account.name)
                        .background(account.id == self.selected ? Color.accentColor : Color.clear)
                        .onTapGesture {self.selected = account.id}
                }
            }
            Divider()
            VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.leading) {
                ForEach(shared.journalLines.filter({$0.accountID == selected})) { line in
                    Text("Line#\(line.id)")
                }
            }
        }
        .onReceive(shared.$selectedTab) { newValue in
            if let id = self.shared.getInitialAccountId(tabIndex: newValue) {
                self.selected = id
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReportsView:View {
    var body:some View {
        Text("Under Construction ...")
    }
}

class SharedObject:ObservableObject {

    @Published var accounts:[Account] = []
    @Published var journalLines:[JournalLine] = []
    @Published var selectedTab:Int = 0

    func getInitialAccountId(tabIndex: Int) -> Int? {
        if tabIndex == 0 {
            return accounts.filter({
                $0.ledger == LedgerType.Accounts
            }).first?.id
        }
        else if tabIndex == 1 {
            return accounts.filter({
                $0.ledger == LedgerType.Budgets
            }).first?.id
        }
        else {
            return accounts.filter({
                $0.ledger == LedgerType.Reports
            }).first?.id
        }
    }

    init() {
        accounts = [
            Account(id: 1, name: "Sales", ledger: .Accounts),
            Account(id: 2, name: "Purchase", ledger: .Accounts),
            Account(id: 3, name: "Forecast", ledger: .Budgets)
        ]
        journalLines = [
            // Line for sales
            JournalLine(id: 1, journalID: 10, accountID: 1, amount: 200),
            JournalLine(id: 2, journalID: 20, accountID: 1, amount: 400),
            // Line for purchase
            JournalLine(id: 3, journalID: 30, accountID: 2, amount: 600),
            JournalLine(id: 4, journalID: 40, accountID: 2, amount: 800)
        ]
    }

}

enum LedgerType: String, CaseIterable {
    case Accounts = "Accounts"
    case Budgets = "Budgets"
    case Reports = "Reports"
}

struct Account:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var ledger:LedgerType
}

struct Payee:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
}

struct Journal:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var date:Date
    var payeeID:Int
    var memo:String?
}

struct JournalLine:Identifiable {
    var id:Int
    var journalID:Int
    var accountID:Int
    var amount:Double
}
```

Comment: I do see/agree that ledger/selected tabs source of truth is the sharedobject.  I made that change and some of the others that you suggested and the issue persisted.  please see added demo code to the original post.  I made an example in a new project that removed a lot of the variables to try to isolate the issue and on my machine at least it still persists.  When the tab is changed it runs ledgerview.init which should change selected to 0 but does not it persists its values over the tabs.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your comment. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: forgive me if i missed something obvious but what did you change? i see nothing that would cause a different behavior.

Comment: There are 2 things, that I have changed. 1. onReceive in ContentView. 2. Changed State to Binding in LedgerView.

Comment: i see it now sorry. binding might work but it is a hack.  contentview should be agnostic of selected account it is only in the ledgerview.  so @State should work correct? I ask because i think this is a bug and not something wrong in my code.

Comment: For this setup, it's not a hack. Like I said, LedgerView is a part of the ContentView. It's the same as keeping the picker inside ContentView. If you really need the LedgerView to be a separate view, then you need a navigationView.

Comment: Ok I can see your argument for ledgerview belonging to content view. However state initialvalue does not work for me in any scenario any view that I make that has its own state view is not refreshed when reinitializing. I can make another demo app showing the issue if needed. I think this is a bug and not an issue with my code in this case at least

Comment: Please do. Note that, state variables have a default value and it can only be modified from within the same view. That's the reason they are declared private and you shouldn't pass state variables in init.

Comment: Ok at lunch when I can break out my Mac I’ll make another mockup sample.

Answer (score -1):

`shared.accounts` doesn't exist. you have never initialized it

```
[...]
  if shared.selectedTab == 0 {
        LedgerView(ledger: .Accounts).environmentObject(SharedObject())
  } else if shared.selectedTab == 1 {
        LedgerView(ledger: .Budgets).environmentObject(SharedObject())

[...]
```

**Edit: Make sure your SceneDelgate also initiates `SharedObject` otherwise it wont work on physical/simulator device**

**--**

**Edit: After running your code and you confirmed you are loading, I ran your code with no change and I don't see any issue, can you look at the gif below and comment what's wrong in what I am seeing?**

[image]

Comment: It does I just didn’t put the loaddata method in the post because it was long so I didn’t think it was helpful

Comment: Got  it, I ran your code with loading fake data from Felix Marianayagam, and  I was able to run it. Can you please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: I doing a Mac app. I think it is related to that. And the selectedtab is from a segmented control one the nstoolbar

Comment: Got it, I will try to replicate with your edit and run a mac app and get back to you.

Comment: I just ran your code as a mac app and it works exactly the same as the simulator above So I don't think I understand the issue. If possible please explain it further to me. Or include the segmented control as well

Comment: I’ll upload the code to github tonight and post a link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209489/discussion-between-eleethesontai-and-muhand-jumah).